# calling the function, which is stored in a string variable

Tags: c#, function, web, dynamic

it may be a duplicate of

[How to dynamically call a class' method in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120228/how-to-dynamically-call-a-class-method-in-net)

and of

[how to achieve calling a function dynamically, thats right the function to be called is decided from database values, using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918431/how-to-achieve-calling-a-function-dynamically-thats-right-the-function-to-be-cal)

but the above two have solutions which as the answers said are complicated, not for a beginner i guess.

and

both solutions contain "type" which from the code i think is for defining the class the method belongs to.

like

```
static void caller(String myclass, String mymethod)
    {
        // Get a type from the string 
        Type type = Type.GetType(myclass);
        // Create an instance of that type
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        // Retrieve the method you are looking for
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(mymethod);
        // Invoke the method on the instance we created above
        methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
    }
```

but my initial web site, only contains one class common to all the functions,

a database which has  "function name"  "func id"

supposed :- function name exactly same as that in code

i only want to achieve the following

- get the string value of function name according to the id mentioned in the text box
- now call that function, whose name is in the string variable

### problem

the methodinfo, needs the "type.GetMethod(mymethod);"

..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call a function you need to specify the type this function is declared on. If all functions you are going to call are declared on a common class you could do the following:

```
static void CallFunc(string mymethod)
{
    // Get a type from the string 
    Type type = typeof(TypeThatContainsCommonFunctions);

    // Create an instance of that type
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Retrieve the method you are looking for
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(mymethod);

    // Invoke the method on the instance we created above
    methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

If the functions you are going to call are static you don't need an instance of the type:

```
static void CallFunc(string mymethod)
{
    // Get a type from the string 
    Type type = typeof(TypeThatContainsCommonFunctions);

    // Retrieve the method you are looking for
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(mymethod);

    // Invoke the method on the type
    methodInfo.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

Comment: with possibly some null checking! ;)

Comment: what do you mean by functions are static ?, how can a function be dynamic? please explain this point, will be great ful thanks

Comment: static and instance methods - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645766(VS.71).aspx

Comment: please help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976211/used-reflection-in-c-works-but-two-errors-need-help-solving-function-called-ju

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions:

1. you need to map function id to
   real function name
2. call
       type.GetMethods() to get list of all
       methods and choose right one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976211/used-reflection-in-c-works-but-two-errors-need-help-solving-function-called-ju    please help