# Why am I getting this Object Reference and Response not Available error?

Tags: c#, reflection, web

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975659/calling-the-function-which-is-stored-in-a-string-variable) I found the following, but there are two errors which I can not solve.

The error is mentioned with the statement causing it as `***//error is***`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Reflection;
//using System.Collections;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string function_name;
        function_name = "one";
        caller(function_name);
    }

    static void caller(String function_name)
    {
        // Get a type from the string 
        Type type = typeof(_Default);
        // Create an instance of that type
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        // Retrieve the method you are looking for
        MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(function_name);
        // Invoke the method on the instance we created above
        methodInfo.Invoke(obj, null);
    }

    public void one()  //function  
    {
        string a = "\n this is the alphabet a \n";

        ***//error is***
        ////Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        ////Label1.Text = "one i called";

        ***//error is***
        /////Response is not available in this context.
         //// Response.Write(a);
    }// function one ends
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to work with the current page (instance of a _default) instead of creating a new one.

Try passing `this` into caller, and replacing `obj` with it.

Comment: i tried what u said, but the "this" does not come within the scope of the function, would you be more specific as to where to add this??

Comment: and why would i pass this in to the caller, the caller has the method name. it has got nothing to do with the obj.   i dont understand..

Comment: @user287745, that's because your `caller` method is static. And you need to call the method on the current page, not on a new page that will never be sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

`Response` belongs to the current `HttpContext` that is set to the Page's `Response` property and you are not getting the right context using `Activator.CreateInstance()` I guess. If you use `HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(a)` instead of `Response.Write(a)`, it works:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(a)
```

For the label case, you need:

```
Label lbl = (HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page).FindControl("Label1") as Label;
lbl.Text = "one i called";
```

This exactly does what you mean I guess. But do you really need to do this, or is it just for practice.

Comment: thanks, your method is great to understand how to access things on the same page indirectly +1