# Objection Creation Predicated by Multiple Regex Values

Tags: c#, regex, design-patterns, factory-pattern

So.. I have a problem with an object creation Pattern.

I have multiple canonicalIds eg.

```
school/1
school/1/class/12/
school/1/class/12/teacher/35
```

I have different objects that represent these and are created from the id. 
what I want to do in a clean way is cycle through the regexs' and determine which object it is.

I'm stuck determining how i should go about matching the regex to a specific factory method.

i want to extract the type which is determined by the last word in the string. but also the id's, then delegating that to a service to retrieve an object from a data store. everything is in place except the glue. I feel there is a better way than having a massive if/else statement

```
class Factory()
 {
  object create(string value)
  {
     if(match1.ismatch(value)) 
     {
       //getting match groups and then using the values to get an object from a data store
       var schoolid=  mactch.group[1].value;
       return new SchoolSerice().GetSchool(schoolid);
     }
     if(match2.ismatch(value)) 
     {          
       var schoolid=  mactch.group[1].value;
       var classid=  mactch.group[2].value;
       return new SchoolSerice().GetClass(schoolid,classid);
     }
  }
```

Comment: can you be bit more specific about what you want to extract..

Comment: edited post with extended data

Comment: I can imagine applying a Strategy pattern here, but honestly I don't see any benefit. The code would be spread out and the logic harder to "see". I suggest you create functions such as `isSchool()`, `isClass()`, etc. to encapsulate the regex logic. It will make your `if` statements more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to need [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28VS.80%29.aspx), which will allow you to dynamically call a method, either `GetSchool`, `GetClass` or whatever. You can look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120228/how-to-dynamically-call-a-class-method-in-net), as my answer is based on it.

I only validated the Regex part, since I have not experienced with reflection, so I just tried to point you in the right direction.

Regex: `"([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\/]+)"`

```
([^\\/]+) # Capture group #1, will capture any character until forward slash, which will be object name
\\/       #forward slash,
([^\\/]+) # Capture group #2, will capture any character until forward slash or end of string, which will be id
```

The method name will be formed from the object name of the last match preceded by Get. All the ids will be put in an `int` array and that array will be passed as the argument for the method call. I am assuming `schoolid` and `classid` are `int`, if you need them as string, just remove `Int32.Parse()`.

---

Example code.

```
 class Factory()
 {
      object create(string value)
      {

           Type type = Type.GetType("SchoolSerice");
           Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
           MethodInfo methodInfo;

           string pattern = "([^\\/]+)\\/([^\\/]+)";
           string methodName = "";
           List<int> argsList = new List<int>();
           int[] argsArray;

           foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(value, pattern)) 
           {
               methodName="get"+char.ToUpper(m.Groups[1].Value[0]) + m.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1);
               argsList.Add(Int32.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value));
           }

           argsArray=argsList.ToArray();
           methodInfo = type.GetMethod(methodName);

           return new methodInfo.Invoke(obj, argsArray);

      }
}
```